# Creating a data.frame with all USA County Unemployment Data

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to create a data.frame with all USA County Unemployment Data from the US Bureau of Labor Statistics:

http://www.bls.gov/lau/#cntyaa

The data has one result per year from 1990 thru 2013.

I had originally planned to use the BLS API, but it looks like they consider each county to be a separate query and the total number of queries would be over their threshold. I now think it might be easier to simply scrape the data from the TXT files they put online, but I am having trouble parsing the data with R. Here is an example page with the data:

http://www.bls.gov/lau/laucnty90.txt # 90 = 1990

I originally tried parsing the file with the `rvest` package. But because the data is all in one `<p>` tag I think that there is not enough HTML structure to the table for that tool.

I then tried `download.file` and `read.table`.  But again, the data seems to not be in the right format for those tools - extra lines at the top and bottom, and the "separating character" is just a space, which confuses R when county names contain spaces.

At the end of the day I just need a data.frame with 3 pieces of data from this file: state FIPS code, county FIPS code and unemployment rate.

I'm now thinking that the easiest way to create this data.frame might be to download the excel files, delete the columns I don't need, remove the extra text at the top and bottom, export to CSV, and then read it into R.

I can certainly do this for each of the 14 years. But I lose some reproducbility with this - other people won't be able to easily verify that I didn't make a mistake in the import process.

Does anyone see an easier way to create this data.frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need a "ruler" to figure out which columns to split at:

```
cat(">",paste0(rep(c(1:9,"+"),14),collapse=""))
cat(">",paste0(sprintf("%08s0/",1:14),collapse=""))
> 123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+
cat(">",paste0(sprintf("%08s0/",1:14),collapse=""))
> 000000010/000000020/000000030/000000040/000000050/000000060/000000070/000000080/000000090/000000100/000000110/000000120/000000130/000000140/
# and paste in the first line of data
> CN0100100000000   01     001   Autauga County, AL                                1990        16,875       15,853      1,022      6.1
```

That lets you figure out where to put the splits andtaking the differnse and shifting by one value gets the widths. Skip  first six rows and then process the data read in as character to avoid the hassles of factors. Remove the commas before coercing to numeric.

```
> dat = read.fwf(url, 
                 widths=diff(c(0,16,21,29,80,86,100,115,125,132)+1), 
                 skip=6,colClasses="character")
> str(dat)
'data.frame':   3219 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ V1: chr  "CN0100100000000 " "CN0100300000000 " "CN0100500000000 " "CN0100700000000 " ...
 $ V2: chr  "  01 " "  01 " "  01 " "  01 " ...
 $ V3: chr  "    001 " "    003 " "    005 " "    007 " ...
 $ V4: chr  "  Autauga County, AL                               " "  Baldwin County, AL                               " "  Barbour County, AL                               " "  Bibb County, AL                                  " ...
 $ V5: chr  " 1990 " " 1990 " " 1990 " " 1990 " ...
 $ V6: chr  "       16,875 " "       46,773 " "       11,458 " "        7,408 " ...
 $ V7: chr  "      15,853   " "      44,492   " "      10,619   " "       6,776   " ...
 $ V8: chr  "   1,022  " "   2,281  " "     839  " "     632  " ...
 $ V9: chr  "    6.1" "    4.9" "    7.3" "    8.5" ...

dat[6:8] <- lapply( dat[6:8], 
                    function(col) as.numeric( gsub("[,]", "", col)) )

> str(dat)
'data.frame':   3219 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ V1: chr  "CN0100100000000 " "CN0100300000000 " "CN0100500000000 " "CN0100700000000 " ...
 $ V2: chr  "  01 " "  01 " "  01 " "  01 " ...
 $ V3: chr  "    001 " "    003 " "    005 " "    007 " ...
 $ V4: chr  "  Autauga County, AL                               " "  Baldwin County, AL                               " "  Barbour County, AL                               " "  Bibb County, AL                                  " ...
 $ V5: chr  " 1990 " " 1990 " " 1990 " " 1990 " ...
 $ V6: num  16875 46773 11458 7408 19130 ...
 $ V7: num  15853 44492 10619 6776 18001 ...
 $ V8: num  1022 2281 839 632 1129 ...
 $ V9: chr  "    6.1" "    4.9" "    7.3" "    8.5" ...

dat[[9]] <- as.numeric( dat[[9]])
```

This could probably be improved by using some "NULL"

Answer (score 6):

That's just a fixed width data file. I don't have time to give you perfect code, but tweaking this should give you what you need:

```
url = 'http://www.bls.gov/lau/laucnty90.txt'
w = c(17, 8, 6, 50, 12, 13, 12, 11) 
dat = read.fwf(url, w, skip=3)
```

Comment: I had never head of fixed-with file format before! Thank you!

Comment: How is this different from @BondedDust answer?

Comment: No different. Just posted earlier.

Comment: It's not fundamentally different in one sense, but it's _practically_ different in that it delivers factors and the wrong number of columns.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an option using the `XLConnect` package to read the spreadsheets directly, avoiding all this business of figuring out column boundaries.

```
get.file <- function(url) {
  require(XLConnect)
  download.file(url,"temp.xlsx",mode="wb")
  wb <- loadWorkbook("temp.xlsx")
  ws <- readWorksheet(wb,1,startRow=7,header=FALSE,drop=list(6))
  ws[!is.na(ws$Col2),]   # remove empty rows at the end
}
pfx  <- "http://www.bls.gov/lau/laucnty"
urls <- paste0(pfx,c(90:99,formatC(0:13,width=2,flag=0)),".xlsx")
result <- do.call(rbind,lapply(urls,get.file))
head(result)
#              Col1 Col2 Col3               Col4 Col5  Col7  Col8 Col9 Col10
# 1 CN0100100000000   01  001 Autauga County, AL 1990 16875 15853 1022   6.1
# 2 CN0100300000000   01  003 Baldwin County, AL 1990 46773 44492 2281   4.9
# 3 CN0100500000000   01  005 Barbour County, AL 1990 11458 10619  839   7.3
# 4 CN0100700000000   01  007    Bibb County, AL 1990  7408  6776  632   8.5
# 5 CN0100900000000   01  009  Blount County, AL 1990 19130 18001 1129   5.9
# 6 CN0101100000000   01  011 Bullock County, AL 1990  4381  3869  512  11.7
```

In the `readWorksheet(...)` call, we skip the first 7 rows because they contain headers, and we drop column 6 because it is blank. Then we remove any rows n the result that contain `NA` in column 2 (the last few rows are notes). Finally we use `lapply(...)` to create a list of all the extracted files, and `do.call(rbind,...)` to combine them all row-wise.

Notice that all the columns are character. There's still some cleaning up you'll need to do. As is typical with these multi-decade datsets, some data is missing and the code for "missing" is not always the same (sometimes `"NA"`, sometimes `"N.A."`, etc.).